# Does it make sense to create a RESTful service that I can send a binary file to?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, grails

As the question states - I want to send a binary file to a webservice. Does it make sense to think of this in a REST kind of way? Does it make sense to "POST" binary data, and how would you set up the receiving web service?

I am working in grails, and I am trying to set up a service that will allow one web service to pass it a file, and then pass the file back after some processing.

Comment: POSTing binary data makes sense, but if the point is just to modify the data and return it, i dunno how RESTful that is.  Not very, i'd think.

Comment: @cHao  Why would you consider that not RESTful?

Comment: @Darrel: Because the principles of REST (as i understand them) say that, simply put, (1) data is state and (2) state has a URL.  A service that just tweaks some data and returns it, without giving it a predictable URL and making it visible on the server, just doesn't seem to fit with the architectural goals of REST as i understand them.

Comment: Well, the data is not exactly tweaked - it is stored on the server..but just no longer in binary form. Information is extracted, parsed, blah blah blah. In other words, some service running out of ProjectController will end up giving me a valid Project still.

Comment: @cHao -- you're mistaken. Data affects state, Resources have URLs.

Comment: @Will: OK, zoom out a bit.  (1) There is no useful state without data of some sort, and there can be no useful data without some way to store it.  And storing requires state of some sort.  So it's not just that the two affect each other -- they're so intimately connected that (again, simply put) data *is* state, and state *is* data.  And (2) A resource is allegedly-useful information of some sort.  IE: data.  IE: *state*.

Comment: @cHao  Look at RFC2616 for one of the uses for POST.  It can be used to pass a representation to a processing resource.  It is perfectly valid for that processing resource to return a representation of a the modified resource.

Comment: @Darrel: I'm aware that in the process of responding to an HTTP request, a script can modify data and return it.  Web sites have had that ability for like 20 years.  I just also expect that when you're talking about REST, that data is now a resource of its own, also addressable by URL.

Comment: @cHao -- if I send a "start" message to a resource representing an automated assembly line, that "start" is NOT the state of the assembly line. The state of the assembly line can be any or all of many measures, for example "running" or "widgets per minute production rate", etc. It is data used to change the state, but not necessarily the state itself. So, no, Data is not State. Data (potentially) affects state. There can also be stateless transformations done upon data. In those cases, the application simply hosts services and does not maintain state per se.

Comment: @cHao The state that is returned to the client as a result of the server side processing is now client state.  At any one point in time in a RESTful system there are two types of state:  Resource state that must have a URL and client application state.  At least that's my perspective.

Comment: @Will:  I have yet to see an example of a "RESTful" service representing an automated assembly line, a data mogrifier, or any other such thing.  *Everything* i've yet seen about REST pretty much explicitly says it's for storing and retrieving data.  But as for the state vs data thing, the "start" message *is* state -- it's just not the state *of the assembly line*, and it's not expected to be preserved.  As i mentioned above, in *every example of explicitly "RESTful" services that i have ever seen*, that state *is* expected to be preserved.

Comment: @cHao -- So, you're suggesting that something such as a web shopping cart with a "Checkout" button can not be RESTful? "Checkout" doesn't store anything, it advances the shopping cart state machine, say to asking for shipping information, but "Checkout" is not, itself, the state. You could POST "item=1234" to http://www.example.com/oneclick and in 2 days a box shows up on your doorstep. What resource is that storing? Certainly not the item. Perhaps the RESTful implementations you've seen don't encompass the totality of applications that a RESTful architecture and style can provide.

Comment: @Will: I'm pretty sure i haven't seen it all.  However, I have seen *nothing* about the other things allegedly RESTful services do.  In order for that to happen, either REST would have to be horribly documented, or those things would be considered not RESTful.  And no, unless that shopping cart stores all of its data on the client (which would be quite unsafe), it's *not* RESTful -- REST mandates that services be *stateless*, meaning no data gets preserved between requests unless it's a resource.  Every shopping cart i know of uses cookies, which are the *opposite* of stateless.

Comment: @cHao  Having the client maintain the state of it's own shopping cart is quite feasible and is completely safe as long as the server treats every request independently.  Which we both know is how it should be.  There are many cases where RESTful services can be used to do far more than just store and retrieve resources.  You are right though, there are not many publicly documented examples.

Comment: @Will Although I completely agree with you in principle.  If I `POST "item=1234"` to `example.com/oneclick`, I certainly hope that there is going to be a `example.com/orders/09889` resource created, or at least something similar.

Comment: @cHao -- or perhaps you are misinformed and your interpretation of REST, stateless, etc. are mistaken. There's that possibility too. Feel free to join us on the REST Mailing List Yahoo group if you'd like to explore that. We're happy to answer any questions you have (this forum is simply too limited for this). Regards...

Comment: @cHao @Will and there is also the #Rest IRC channel on Freenode that quite a few of us frequent.

Comment: @Darrel: i didn't say "not many".  I said "not *any* ".  It's not like i haven't looked.  I just haven't seen any examples that are RESTful *and* provide the other operations alleged to be RESTful here.  If you can provide a link to one, i'd be forever grateful -- i rather dislike being misinformed.  :)  But til then, i have to go by what i've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly valid scenario.  Just set the request content-type to `application/octet-stream` and the server can read the stream of bytes and do whatever it wants with it.

Comment: How does this work on the grails side of things? Can I simply set up the closure and use the params field to pull the byte array out of it?

Comment: Sorry, that's out of my field of expertise.  But if Grails can't handle it, find a new REST framework :-)

Comment: Yah - it probably can, I am just searching for examples. All of the online examples I have found they are POSTing XML data which is easy to get in grails

Comment: Look at JAX-RS plugin for Grails. This one can do anything you want :)